# How to make sure map is loaded with google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

I am using `google-map-react` and need to have access to the `map`.

I access the ref through doing something like:

`<GoogleMap ref={ref => this.map = ref} />`

When I call the ref on `componentDidMount()` like so `this.map.map_` it returns null because the map has not loaded yet. I need a way to access this when the component mounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [onGoogleApiLoaded](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md#ongoogleapiloaded-func):

```
handleGoogleApiLoaded = ({map, maps}) => {
  map...
}

<GoogleMap  
  onGoogleApiLoaded={this.handleGoogleApiLoaded}
  yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
/>
```

Comment: If I set this to something like `this.map = map` in `componentDidMount()` it returns `undefined`. I may be able to make something work with this though

Comment: @TaylorAustin the thing is, you don't need `componentDidMount` there is a hook that will get called once the google map has loaded. See the edit.

Comment: Yeah that is what I ended up doing after I thought about it. Thank you, I know this is a "dangerous" way of doing this according to the warning. What could go wrong? And is there any other way of doing this with using `ref={ref => ref}`

Comment: Using ref to access internal component property is a "hacky" way, that's why there is no straight-forward way to do it. You would need to wait until GoogleMap and API are loaded and then use the ref. But you can't easily determine when this will happen.